# Error in building linphone on windows using Cygwin

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk, linphone, ndk-build

It has been more than 4 days now and I am still not able to make the build using cygwin. I have almost done everything necessary to make a successful build but stuck at the same error which i faced 3 days ago.

I have done everything said in the readme file.
when i run Makefile in the top directory it says commands not found. When I run prepare_sorces.sh it says commands not found.

When i run make command i receive an error of which i have not found solution yet.

If anyone has a solution to my problem then please help me out in this because now I am loosing hope that can i really build it.
Any help will be appreciated.
I have visited almost every link on the internet but still I do not have any solution.
Thanks in advance

The error is,

enabling runtime_cpu_detect

Requested CPU 'cortex-a8' not supported by compiler

Configuration failed. This could reflect a misconfiguration of your
toolchains, improper options selected, or another problem. If you
don't see any useful error messages above, the next step is to look
at the configure error log file (config.log) to determine what
configure was trying to do when it died.
VP8 prepare stage failed.
Makefile:24: recipe for target 'prepare-vpx' failed
make: *** [prepare-vpx] Error 1

Comment: Building such library on Windows may be a frustrating experience. I would recommend to install Ubuntu on a Virtual Box (all free), and be much happier.

Comment: Regarding your specific error message, its cause is that the cross-compilation toolchain was not set up correctly. This is kind of problems that can take much of your time, and even justify professional services.

Comment: But if there is any solution that can help me in windows would be really helpful. I did R&D on this error and there it said you need to specify tha ndk path correctly which i have done but still i get the same errors. This was the one and only solution the i came across.

Comment: There are too many subtle Windows settings that may go wrong. I am afraid you need a 1-on-1 session with an expert who can assist you.

Comment: I tried doing it on ubuntu but still i am facing errors.

It says,
Error- Expected verb after global parameters but found NDK instead.

What does this mean??
I have no clue. Please can anybody help me with this..

Comment: "unexpected verb"? Please post complete clean build log (via pastebin.com).

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vuj1v5k0mipxh9p/build%20log?dl=0

This is the link to my build log. PLease go through it

Comment: I would suggest that you upgrade to latest NDK (r10c for October'14) and not use `crystax` for such delicate task. Create a clean standalone toolchain for gcc 4.9, and try again. At any rate, building ffmpeg (which is part of linphone) for Android in cygwin is a nightmare, see many questions here on SO and elsewhere.

Comment: do i have to give the path for ndk and sdk in the Makefile??

Comment: You must prepare a standalone toolchain as explained in NDK documents. You will specify the path to this toolchain to `make` some way. Hardcoding paths in `Makefile` is not considered good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using mac for compilation. i too was working with compiling the code on windows but was finally able to compile the code successfully from mac 32 bit.